# Calculating ECEF position of gps satellite?

Tags: coordinate-system, gps, geometry-conversion, ecef

I am calculating the ECEF positions of satellites but the results are not what I expected.I'll show my code below but I'm following the gps specification(converting to radians from semicircles and the formulas given in https://ascelibrary.org/doi/pdf/10.1061/9780784411506.ap03)

[image: GPS_SPEC]

I am a little confused about the time formulas as they seem to overlap and aren't really clear what specific parameters are needed so perhaps this is the reason why my ecef positions are not what I expect or perhaps its the conversion from semi-circles to radians.

```
    M_0 = GPS_DF['MA_RT'][238]*np.pi
e = GPS_DF['Eccentricity'][238]           ### Eccentricity (Dimensionless)

CUC = GPS_DF['Cuc'][238]                    ### Amplitude of the cosine harmonic correction term,
                                             #   to the argument of latitude (Radians)

CUS = GPS_DF['Cus'][238]                    ### Amplitude of the sine harmonic correction term,
                                             #   to the argument of latitude (Radians)

CRC = GPS_DF['Crc'][238]                    ### Amplitude of the cosine harmonic correction term,
                                             #   to the orbit radius (Meters)


CRS = GPS_DF['Crs'][238]                   ###  Amplitude of the sine harmonic correction term,
                                             #   to the orbit radius (Meters)


CIC = GPS_DF['Cic'][238]                   ###  Amplitude of the cosine harmonic correction term,
                                            #    to the angle of inclination (Radians)


CIS = GPS_DF['Cis'][238]                   ###  Amplitude of the sine harmonic correction term,
                                            #    to the angle of inclination (Radians)


i0 = GPS_DF['Inc_RT'][238]*np.pi                     ###  Inclination angle at reference time (Radians)
idot = GPS_DF['ROIA'][238]*np.pi                 ###  Rate of inclination angle (Radians per second)
omega = GPS_DF['Peri_RT'][238]*np.pi               ###  Argument of perigee (Radians)
OMEGA0 = GPS_DF['LOAN'][238]*np.pi             ###  Argument of perigee (Radians)
OMEGAdot = GPS_DF['RORA'][238]*np.pi      ###  Reference rate of right ascension (Radians per second)

M_k = M_0 + n*t_k                             ### Mean Anomaly (Radians)

E_1 = M_k + e*np.sin(M_k)                     ### Iteration 1 of eccentric anomaly (Radians)
E_k = M_k + e*np.sin(E_1)                     ### Iteration 2 of eccentric anomaly (Radians)

TOP = np.cos(E_k) - e                         ### Numerator of cosine of true anomaly calc (Radians)
BOTTOM = 1 - (e*np.cos(E_k))                  ### Denominator of cosine of true anomaly calc (Radians)

cos_vk = TOP/BOTTOM                           ### Cosine of true anomaly (Radians)
v_k = np.arccos(cos_vk)                       ### True Anomaly (Radians)

phi_k = v_k + omega                           ### Argument of Latitude (Radians)

lat_corrector = (CUC*np.cos(2*phi_k)          ### Argument of latitude correction (Radians)
                 + CUS*np.sin(2*phi_k))
rad_corrector = (CRC*np.cos(2*phi_k)          ### Radius Correction (Meters)
                 + CRS*np.sin(2*phi_k))
inc_corrector = (CIC*np.cos(2*phi_k)          ### Inclination Correction (Radians)
                 + CIS*np.sin(2*phi_k))

LAT_CORRECTED = phi_k + lat_corrector         ### Corrected Argument of Latitude (Radians)

RAD_CORRECTED = (A*(1-e*np.cos(E_k))          ### Corrected Radius (Meters)
                 + rad_corrector)

INC_CORRECTED = i0 + idot*t_k + inc_corrector     ### Corrected Inclination (Radians)

X_prime = RAD_CORRECTED*np.cos(LAT_CORRECTED) ### X Position in the orbital plane (Meters)
Y_prime = RAD_CORRECTED*np.sin(LAT_CORRECTED) ### Y Position in the orbital plane (Meters)

LOAN_CORRECTED = (OMEGA0                      ### Corrected Longitude of Ascending Node (Radians)
                  +(OMEGAdot-Earth_rot_rate)*t_k
                  -(Earth_rot_rate*GPS_DF['Toe'][238]))

X_k = (X_prime*np.cos(LOAN_CORRECTED)         ### ECEF X Position (Meters)
       - Y_prime*np.sin(LOAN_CORRECTED)*np.cos(INC_CORRECTED))
Y_k = (X_prime*np.sin(LOAN_CORRECTED)         ### ECEF Y Position (Meters)
       + Y_prime*np.cos(LOAN_CORRECTED)*np.cos(INC_CORRECTED))
Z_k = Y_prime*np.sin(INC_CORRECTED)           ### ECEF Z Position (Meters)
```

[image: Row Values]
[image: Row Values_2]
[image: Row Values_3]